# Multiple Website Backup

Tags: backup, remote-backup

Does anyone know of a script or program that can be used for backing up multiple websites?

Ideally, I would like the have it setup on a server where the backups will be stored.

I would like to be able to add the website login info, and it connects and creates a zip file or similar that it would then be sent back to the remote server to be saved as a backup etc...

But it would also need to be able to be set up as a cron so it backed up everyday at least?

I can find PC to Server backups that a similar, but no server to server remote backup scripts etc...

It would be heavily used, and needs to be a gui so the less techy can use it too?

Does anyone know of anything similar to what we need?

Comment: A bit of clarification...

Server A would hold the script (so it does not need to be installed on every different server) and the backups...

But it needs to get the files/SQL dump from Server B, C & D and send them back to Server A to be stored...

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: You might want to clarify what exactly will be backed up.  If you just want to backup your PHP/JSP/ASPX/whatever files, you will be better off keeping a master copy in source control (e.g. GIT/SVN) and deploying to the server from there.  If you have a DB to be backed up / files that get written / etc to backup, clarify what those files are.

Comment: Basically, we want to be able to offer a backup service to our clients. We do alot of joomla & wordpress sites, as well as just plain HTML/PHP standard sites. So we are just looking at basically creating a backup/restore service to our clients. We would need to backup these files (Some the clients change themselves) and any DB attached to the sites... We would prefer a service that had already been tried and tested over having to develop one ourselves...?

Answer (score 0):

- HTTP-Track website mirroring utility.
- Wget and scripts
- RSync and FTP login (or SFTP for security)
- Git can be used for backup and has security features and networking ability.
- 7Zip can be called from the command line to create a zip file.

In any case you will need to implement either secure FTP (SSH secured) OR a password-secured upload form.  If you feel clever you might use WebDAV.

Comment: Thanks! We are trying to avoid having to put something together ourselves... Something tired and tested, that may only need to be modified would be better, if its out there lol

Comment: Any service you can find will need significant customization for you to use it in your specific case.  The above options all take a lot of the heavy lifting out of the work, and can be easily scripted and automated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Put a **backup generator script on each website** (outputting a ZIP)
2. Protect its access with a .htpasswd file
3. On the backupserver, make a **cron script download all the backups and store them**